# Set space between list and following paragraph to equal one line

Tags: spacing, lists, enumitem

My question is best formulated with an example, which is given below. I've tried to play with `topsep`, but that seems to modify the space both before and after the list. I need to only modify the space after the list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace, enumitem,titlesec}
\singlespacing
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesection.}{.5em}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{3ex}{1ex}
\begin{document}
\section*{My first section}
This is the first paragraph of the first subsection in my first section.

This is the second paragraph.\\

\noindent Now this will be the first paragraph of the second subsection in my first section.

And this the second paragraph. You get the idea now.

\section*{My second section}
The first paragraph of the first subsection. This paragraph contains a list.
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
    \item The first item
    \item The second item
\end{itemize}
\noindent The first paragraph continues here. Or you might call it the second paragraph -- makes no difference to me.\\

\noindent This, however, is the second subsection. This will also contain a list. But this time the list will end the subsection.
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
    \item The first item
    \item The second item
\end{itemize}
\noindent This is the third subsection. How do I get the space between the list above and this subsection to be \emph{exactly} the same as between two subsections elsewhere in my letter? As it is now, the space it too small -- it looks like another paragraph rather than another subsection.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note you don't need `\noindent ` after the list, it won't be indented if it is a continuation of the previous paragraph.

Comment: Try to play with `after*`, for example `\begin{itemize}[noitemsep,after*=\vspace{2mm}]`

Comment: @karlkoeller But how do I get it to equal the distance between two subsections elsewhere - which is enforced with ``\\``? In other words, if I change ``\singlespacing`` to ``\doublespacing``, the space after the list should follow suit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code (requires `calc` package). I'm not sure if the right length is `\baselineskip-\topsep`, anyway...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace, enumitem,titlesec}
\usepackage{calc}

\singlespacing
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesection.}{.5em}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{3ex}{1ex}

\newlength{\mylength}
\setlength{\mylength}{\baselineskip-\topsep}

\begin{document}
\section*{My first section}
This is the first paragraph of the first subsection in my first section.

This is the second paragraph.\
\noindent Now this will be the first paragraph of the second subsection in my first section.

And this the second paragraph. You get the idea now.

\section*{My second section}
The first paragraph of the first subsection. This paragraph contains a list.
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
    \item The first item
    \item The second item
\end{itemize}
The first paragraph continues here. Or you might call it the second paragraph -- makes no difference to me.\
\noindent This, however, is the second subsection. This will also contain a list. But this time the list will end the subsection.
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep,after*=\vspace{\mylength}]
    \item The first item
    \item The second item
\end{itemize}
This is the third subsection. How do I get the space between the list above and this subsection to be \emph{exactly} the same as between two subsections elsewhere in my letter? As it is now, the space it too small -- it looks like another paragraph rather than another subsection.
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Note the spacing after the latter `itemize`.

I've defined a new length `mylenght` and set it to `\baselineskip-\topsep`. Then, `\begin{itemize}[noitemsep,after*=\vspace{\mylength}]` should do what you want.

If you want to set that value for all lists you can remove `after*=\vspace{\mylength}` from the specific list and add

```
\setlist{after*=\vspace{\mylength}}
```

to set it globally.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of introducing your subsections with `\\`, which is almost always wrong in plain text, you can use one of the built in commands such as `\bigbreak`.  If this is not big enough for you, you can define your own version as in the following (with perhaps an exaggerated spacing):

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace,enumitem,titlesec}
\singlespacing
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesection.}{.5em}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{3ex}{1ex}

\newlength{\mysubsectionskip}
\setlength{\mysubsectionskip}{26pt plus 4pt minus 4pt}
\newcommand{\subsectionbreak}{\par\ifdim\lastskip<\mysubsectionskip
\removelastskip\penalty -200 \vspace{\mysubsectionskip} \fi}

\begin{document}

\section*{My first section}
This is the first paragraph of the first subsection in my first section.

This is the second paragraph.

\subsectionbreak

\noindent Now this will be the first paragraph of the second subsection in my first section.

And this the second paragraph. You get the idea now.

\section*{My second section}
The first paragraph of the first subsection. This paragraph contains a list.
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
    \item The first item
    \item The second item
\end{itemize}
\noindent The first paragraph continues here. Or you might call it the
second paragraph -- makes no difference to me.

\subsectionbreak

\noindent This, however, is the second subsection. This will also contain a list. But this time the list will end the subsection.
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
    \item The first item
    \item The second item
\end{itemize}

\subsectionbreak
\noindent This is the third subsection. How do I get the space between
the list above and this subsection to be \emph{exactly} the same as
between two subsections elsewhere in my letter? As it is now, the
space it too small -- it looks like another paragraph rather than
another subsection.

\end{document}
```

Just like `\bigbreak` this `\subsectionbreak` command looks at the last vertical space added and if it is smaller than `\mysubsectionskip` replaces it by that value.  Note that is usual to leave some flexibility in these lengths.  If you want it completely rigid then set `\mysubsectionskip` to say `26pt`.  You could also consider putting `\nointerlineskip` before the `\ifdim` of the definition of `\sectionbreak`.  These two together would make the space exactly `26pt`.

Of course, one could use `\bigbreak` and redefine `\bigskipamount` to the value you wish to use, but you may get caught out by this value being used at other places in the document's design.

In all the above, `26pt` was chosen as an exaggerated value;  `12pt` would give you the standard baselineskip.

*ADDED* As daleif points out, you can build a version of the macro that automatically ensures the following paragraph is not indented as follows:

```
\newlength{\mysubsectionskip}
\setlength{\mysubsectionskip}{26pt plus 4pt minus 4pt}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\subsectionbreak}{\par\ifdim\lastskip<\mysubsectionskip
\removelastskip\penalty -200 \vspace{\mysubsectionskip} \fi
\@afterindentfalse\@afterheading}
\makeatother
```

This uses LaTeX's internal `\@afterheading` which reacts to the setting of the switch `\@afterindent`.  As these names contain `@` we need to enclose the code in a `\makeatletter  / \makeatother` pair.

Comment: take a look at the definition of `\fancybreak` in the `memoir` source, then you can build the noindent-ness into the macro.

Comment: @daleif That's a good idea.  Code added.

Comment: Since ``\baselineskip`` is what I use in letters of this format to separate and introduce subsections, wouldn't be easier to use ``titlesec`` and somehow reformat ``subsection``? I.e. that a subsection has ``\baselineskip`` before it, has no heading, and no indentation?

Comment: If you wanted to use `titlesec` you could try `\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{}{}{0pt}{}` and `\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{0pt}` and write `\subsection*{}` each time.

Comment: @AndrewSwann The option needs to be ``[drop]``, not ``[runin]``.

Comment: @Sverre Yes, `drop` is the correct `titlesec` option.